# Background-Image (Duda on div de tamaño fijo)

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap

Hola buenos días a todos, estimados mi consulta es la siguiente: necesito que un div con un tamaño determinado (300px) y un `widht` de 100% tenga una imagen de fondo, lo consigo, pero el tema es que cuando paso por ese `div` hace una especie de scroll sobre la imagen, y quiero que quede como "fijo"...

Tengo este css:

```
#fullTurismoIndex{
  background: url(../img/background_frontis.jpg) no-repeat ; 
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

y el html lo tengo asi:

```
 <!--TURISMO-->
<section id="fullTurismoIndex" class="">
  <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h3>TURISMO</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Aclaro que probé con `cover` en la propiedad del `background` y tampoco me resultó.

Saludos a todos y gracias desde ya

Comment: Probando tu código funciona sin problema, la imagen de fondo permanece fija

Comment: Intenta hacer una resolución mas pequeña y veras que cuando se hace scroll la imágen tambien se mueve.

Comment: Tu respuesta es correcta

Comment: lo pruebo en html puro y me funciona...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Añade `background-attachment: fixed;` al estilo css de `#fullTurismoIndex` y la imagen nunca se movera del sitio!

Answer (score 0):

Agrega un overflow: hidden a tu propiedad en css;

```
#fullTurismoIndex{
     width: 100%;
     height: 300px;
     overflow: hidden;
     background: url(../img/background_frontis.jpg) no-repeat ;
}
```

Comment: creo que no has entendido bien lo que queria decir Nicolas Ezequiel Almonacid

Comment: jeje cito: "Cuando paso por ese div hace una especie de scroll sobre la imagen"

Comment: claro, se referia que la imagen baja con el documento y lo que quiere es que siempre sea fija, aunque el documento baje